# ROS dependency auto-generators

Tags: ros, ros2

I've been using ROS for a while but have only recently wondered - is it possible to automate the process of generating/filling in the depencies in `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` files? From what I understand, this is a manual process, with `ros2 pkg` providing some help with flags like `--build-type` or `dependencies`.

Would be nice if there was a way to scan the files in `src` to check new changes to the files to determine if there are missing dependencies and automatically determine the build type. Just wondering if something like this exists, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a feature like this exists. The point of the `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` is to have control over your code.

Once all the manual setup is done, you can run `rosdep` to install all the dependencies for that package, which is the nice automation part.